# Popup while session timeout

Tags: .net, asp.net, session, session-state, session-timeout

How to set a pop up message box saying... "please end your session and start again" in my asp.net webform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first shoot is JS script with simple time counter. You should set max session time value and decrease it every one second - if == 0 then popup some message.
When you reload page - counter will be reseted and start counting again.

Good luck !

hsz

Comment: Here you have a sample JS code:
http://www.java-scripts.net/javascripts/Countdown-Timer.phtml

Comment: what i need to undestand is how to check whether the session has been timed out?