# Session problem in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state, session-timeout

I have an asp.net website, where there is no where session is implemented.

But i could see the session is timing out when i take the website after deploying in the production server ...

i checked the session entries in the web.config file... and searched session in the code..

nowhere i find the entry...

now i want to put a message box while session timeout ..how to do this..please help!!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get your question at the moment: Why do you need to see the session timout and how do you see it in the moment? Are we speaking from a live envoirement with ISS in background or from IDE's like Visual Studio?

Comment: Maybe you could post the code where the session is timing out, and your session entries from web.config? Otherwise it's pretty hard to help.

Comment: You asked the same question two hours ago [Popup while session timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838760/popup-while-session-timeout)

Comment: i couldn't post the code since i didn't find any entries ...for session in the code or web.config ... when i deployed the code in my iis server. when i take the link after deploying and keep untouched for one hour...session will timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your aspx html code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout('SessionTimeout()', <%= Session.Timeout * 60 * 1000 %>);
    function SessionTimeout() {
        alert(<%= "'Session time out!!'" %>);
        window.location = "Default.aspx"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkssssssssssssss

Comment: you can define the session timeout in web.config.

Comment: 'Session.Timeout * 60 * 19000' for 19 sec :-)

Comment: @Eagle_one don't do that, change the timeout in web.config otherwise the `SessionTimeout` function will be called at a different time than the accentual session timeout...

Comment: Peter..Thanks I know I answered the second question only ;-)

Comment: @Eagle_one yes you did, but you gave a incorrect solution to the problem, while your solution would change the timeout it would not change the actual session timeout, also your calculation is a bit of it would change it to 380 minutes...

Answer (score 2):

you could check this in your web.config and increase time...

```
<sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
```

also check your sessionStatemode...

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"></sessionState>
```

Comment: there is no entries like above in my web.config

Comment: read this article and add as per your requirement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx